# How to convert array of srting with multiple same keys to JSON Object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, api-gateway

I have an array which I have extracted from query string which looks like below:

var arr = 'field1=12345&status=New&status=Assigned&status=In Progress&field2=2&field3=abc&feild4=10'

I need to convert this array to JSON object. I am using the below code:

```
    const arr = 'field1=12345&status=New&status=Assigned&status=In Progress&field2=2&field3=abc&feild4=10'

function arrayToObject(query) {
    const uri = decodeURIComponent(query);
    const chunks = uri.split('&');
    const params = {}
    var chunk = {}
    for (var i=0; i < chunks.length ; i++) {
        chunk = chunks[i].split('=');
        console.log(chunk)
        params[chunk[0]] = chunk[1];
        }

    return params;
}
const querySt = arrayToObject(decodedQueryString);
const qSt = JSON.stringify(querySt);

console.log(qSt)
```

I am getting the below output:
{"feild1":"12345","status":"In Progress","feild2":"2","feild3":"abc","feild4":"10"}

But I need an output like this:
{"feild1":"12345","status"::["New", "Assigned", "In Progress"],"feild2":"2","feild3":"abc","feild4":"10"}

Can anyone help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
const arr = 'field1=12345&status=New&status=Assigned&status=In Progress&field2=2&field3=abc&feild4=10'

function arrayToObject(query) {
    const uri = decodeURIComponent(query);
    const chunks = uri.split('&');
    const params = {}
    var chunk = {}
    for (var i=0; i < chunks.length ; i++) {
        chunk = chunks[i].split('=');
        console.log(chunk)
        if (params[chunk[0]]){
        params[chunk[0]] = Array.isArray(params[chunk[0]]) ? [...params[chunk[0]], chunk[1]] : [params[chunk[0]], chunk[1]];
        } else {
        params[chunk[0]] = chunk[1];
        }
        }

    return params;
}
const querySt = arrayToObject(arr);
const qSt = JSON.stringify(querySt);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the string to a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object. Get the keys from the object, and pass them through a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) to get the unique key. Now reduce the array of keys to an object, and use [`URLSearchParams.get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get) for single value keys, and [`URLSearchParams.getAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/getAll) for multiple values keys (like `status`):

```js
const str = 'field1=12345&status=New&status=Assigned&status=In Progress&field2=2&field3=abc&feild4=10'

const params = new URLSearchParams(str)

const result = [...new Set([...params.keys()])]
  .reduce((acc, key) => {
    acc[key] = key === 'status' 
      ? params.getAll(key)
      : params.get(key)  
    
    return acc
  }, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result))
```